# Interior/closure/complement of a translate of a subset of a topological group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

While I was trying to solve an Exercize about the Vaught trasforms (Descriptive Set theory), I conjectured the following:

> **Conjecture:** Let $G$ be a topological group (even Polish whenever necessary) and $H\subseteq G$ a subset. Then for every $g\in G$
>   $$(1) (H)^°g=(Hg)^°,$$
>   $$(2) \overline{H}g=\overline{Hg},$$
>   $$(3) (H)^cg=(Hg)^c,$$
>   where $(.)^°$ is the interior operator, $\overline{(.)}$ is the closure operator and $(.)^c$ is the complementation.

**Question:** is the above conjecture true?

**Attempt:** $(1)$ $(\subseteq)$ is obvious; for the converse $(\supseteq)$, notice that 
$$x\in (Hg)^°\iff \text{$\exists U(x)$ nhbd s.t. $U(x)\subseteq Hg$},$$
$$y\in (H)^°\iff \text{$\exists U(y)$ nhbd s.t. $U(y)\subseteq H$}$$
If $x\in (Hg)^°$, then $x=hg$ and $U(h)g$ is an open nhbd of $x$ contained in $Hg$ and hence $U(h)$ is an open nhbd of $h$ in $H$.

Is this reasoning right?
If it is, then in a similar way $(2)$ can be shown.

However, $(3)$ is more difficult for me and I'm looking for a proof (or a counterexample, whenever $(3)$ does not hold).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) does hold, for the ($\supseteq$)direction, just notice $U(x)g^{-1}\subseteq H$ is an open nbhd of $h$ if $x=hg$.

(2) is similar.

(3) is false. Let $G=H=\Bbb Z$ and $g=2$. Then $(H)^cg=\emptyset$, but $(Hg)^c=\text{the set of all odd numbers}$.

Comment: To sum up, $(1),(2)$ holds and $(3)$ does not, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @LBJFS Yeah, interior and closure are actually dual concepts, so if (1) is true, there shouldn't be much difficulty in verifying (2).

Comment: Yes, I verified $(2)$ in a similar way... and hence I thought I could deduce $(2)$ from $(1)$ by using $(3)$, but this is not the case.